# Is it possible to create a query based on two foreign keys using the EntityManagerInterface class?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I trying to create a query with a two-level reference that will return offers.

Already I using createQueryBuilder method, anyway my query looks very good. But I still has this problem:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 47 near 'CarManufacturer': Error: Class App\Entity\Offer has no field or association named model.CarManufacturer

```php
//$manufacturer - string from GET
public function getOffersByManufacturer($manufacturer):
    {
       return $this->em->getRepository(Offer::class)
            ->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p')
            ->andWhere('p.model.CarManufacturer = :manufacturer')
            ->setParameter('manufacturer', $manufacturer)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
    }
```

Anyway Table offer has a foreign key (ManyToOne) to Model and next Model(Entity) has foreign key (ManyToOne) to CarManufacturer(Entity)

I would like to get something like this using spring

```java
public List<Offer> getOffersByManufacturer(int manuacturerId):
{
   String jpql = "select o from Offer o where o.carModel.manufacturer.id = :id order by o.title";
   TypedQuery<Offer> query = em.createQuery(jpql, Offer.class);
   query.setParameter("id", manuacturerId);
   return query.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
->andWhere('p.model.CarManufacturer = :manufacturer')
```

With:

```
->innerJoin('p.model', 'm')
->andWhere('m.CarManufacturer = :manufacturer')
```

Or:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;

->innerJoin('p.model', 'm', Join::WITH, 'm.CarManufacturer = :manufacturer')
```